# Create area that cell tower covers

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial-query

I have a dataset with cell tower information, as you can see below. The lat and lon fields are the location of the tower.

[image]

The objective is to get the area (geometry) of the sector the cell tower covers, from start_angle to end_angle. As you can see in the next image, using the first row of the dataset as example, I can obtain the lines from start_angle 275 and end_angle 35, but I want the rest of the buffer to disappear.

[image]

**Query used:**

This first query is used to create and rotate the lines from start_angle and end_angle and also a line with 0 degrees.

```
WITH vertices AS
(SELECT 
      id,
 start_angle,
 end_angle,
      (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path[1] AS v_id, 
      (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS vertex
FROM celulas
), teste as
(SELECT
    id,
    v_id,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Translate(ST_Rotate(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 1.0,0.0), 
                                                  ST_MakePoint(-1.0,0.0)),
                                      radians(start_angle * -1)), ST_X(vertex), ST_Y(Vertex)),
                                      ST_SRID(vertex)) AS startline,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Translate(ST_Rotate(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 1.0,0.0), 
                                                  ST_MakePoint(-1.0,0.0)),
                                      radians(end_angle * -1)), ST_X(vertex), ST_Y(Vertex)),
                                      ST_SRID(vertex)) AS endline,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Translate(ST_Rotate(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 1.0,0.0), 
                                                  ST_MakePoint(-1.0,0.0)),
                                      radians(0)), ST_X(vertex), ST_Y(Vertex)),
                                      ST_SRID(vertex)) AS midline
    
FROM vertices
)
```

I also used the next query to union all geometries: the radius buffer and the lines

```
select St_intersection(st_split(buffer, midline), st_split(buffer, angulo))
from angulo
```

Comment: Hey there. What do you exactly mean by "I want the rest of the buffer to disappear"?

Comment: Hello. As you can see in the image I have the entire radius of the cell tower. But I only want to show the sector from the start_angle to the end_angle, i.e., from 275 degrees to 35. The rest of the circle doesnt matter.

Comment: Okay. Can you also add to your question the query you used to create this geometry/buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Let's create us a handy [inline function on the composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) of your relation specifically.

Also, and first off, let's create two equally handy support functions for all sorts of use cases in this context; getting the *clockwise (CW)* (and, since we're at it, also the *counterclockwise (CW)*) angular difference in degree between two azimuths:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CWAngle(
  IN    sdeg FLOAT,
  IN    edeg FLOAT,
  OUT   ddeg  FLOAT
) LANGUAGE SQL AS
  $$
    SELECT CASE (sdeg <= edeg)
             WHEN TRUE THEN
               edeg - sdeg
             ELSE
               360.0 - sdeg + edeg
           END;
  $$
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CCWAngle(
  IN    sdeg FLOAT,
  IN    edeg FLOAT,
  OUT   ddeg  FLOAT
) LANGUAGE SQL AS
  $$
    SELECT 360.0 - CWAngle(sdeg, edeg);
  $$
;
```

*There may or may not be more efficient ways, or more idiomatic code; this works well enough.*

Now, the concept of the following function is to create a 'wedge', your sector, of a circle by projecting the center point along the circle segment between `start_angle` and `end_angle` at the given `"radius"`; we will project `<degrees_between_angles>/FLOOR(<degrees_between_angles>)` points, so every `1 <= step < 2`, with `step` being *degrees* (which is a lot; `ST_Buffer` defaults to a circle having 8 vertices per quarter circle):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sector(
    rec spatial.celulas
) RETURNS GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4236) AS
  $$
    DECLARE
      delta FLOAT := CWAngle(rec.start_angle, rec.end_angle);
      step  FLOAT := delta / FLOOR(delta);
      
      wedge GEOMETRY(POINT)[];
      
    BEGIN
      wedge := wedge || ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(rec.lon, rec.lat), 4326);
  
      FOR n IN 0..FLOOR(delta)
        LOOP
          wedge := wedge || ST_Project(wedge[1]::GEOGRAPHY, rec."radius", RADIANS(MOD(rec.start_angle+(n*step)::NUMERIC, 360.0::NUMERIC)))::GEOMETRY;
        END LOOP
      ;
  
      wedge := wedge || wedge[1];
      
      RETURN ST_MakePolygon(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(wedge), 4326));
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This assumes

- that the `CWAngle` function is present; change to `CCWAngle` in this function if needed
- that `start_angle` -> `end_angle` is in *clockwise direction*
- that `"radius"` is in *meter*
- the exact relation and column names of your example, i.e `celulas.lat, celulas.lon, celulas."radius", celulas.start_angle, celulas.end_angle`; you need to alter all occurences of these identifiers in the function accordingly if they are actually different

This function is thus **specific to the relation in your example**, and you can call it like a *relation qualified column*:

```
SELECT [*,] celulas.sector AS geom
FROM   celulas
;
```

---

Alternatively, [here is a more general function](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/33b3f92f45039db8dea6bb2c9e2d8b46) based on the same concept, which also allows to set the max vertices per quarter circle, and an optional inner radius.